# button not inside event?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using pygame for my xbox one control and there should be something named button but it throws an error saying `AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'button'`

this is the entire code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
joysticks = []
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
keepPlaying = True

# for al the connected joysticks
for i in range(0, pygame.joystick.get_count()):
    # create an Joystick object in our list
    joysticks.append(pygame.joystick.Joystick(i))
    # initialize them all (-1 means loop forever)
    joysticks[-1].init()
    # print a statement telling what the name of the controller is
    print ("Detected joystick "),joysticks[-1].get_name(),"'"
while keepPlaying:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.button == 0:
            print ("A Has Been Pressed")
```

when i press a it prints `<Event(1539-JoyButtonDown {'joy': 0, 'instance_id': 0, 'button': 0})>` there should be a button attrabute but it throws the error instead

Comment: `joysticks[-1]` does NOT mean "loop forever",  It means "fetch the last one in the list".  In this case, that's what you want.  Are you getting ANY events from the joystick?  Maybe you have the numbering wrong

Comment: im pretty sure its the numbering but i dont know why because it should have a button atribute but it errors saying it dosnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each event type generates a [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) object with different attributes. The `button` attribute is not defined for all event objects. You can just get the `button` attribute from a mouse or joystick event like `JOYBUTTONUP` or `JOYBUTTONDOWN`. However all event objects have a `type` attribute. Check the event `type` attribute before the `button` attribute (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)):

```py
while keepPlaying:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 0:
                print ("A Has Been Pressed")
```

Comment: thank you i didnt understand the fact that i needed to use both `pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN` and `if event.button = 0`